# How to check if an object is iterable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I check if an object is iterable in Ruby?

That is, I want a method that cleanly checks if an object is iterable, like so:

```
def is_iterable(my_object)
  ..
end
```

I'm really not sure where to start on this short of explicitly naming classes from within the method.

**Edit:**
For my purposes, let's say iterable is something you can do .each to.

Comment: In general, if you're planning on saying "title says it all", you haven't included enough information.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> For my purposes, let's say iterable is something you can do `.each` to.

You can just ask if this object has this method

```
def iterable?(object)
  object.respond_to?(:each)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. `nil..nil` is a Range object and responds to `each`, but is not iterable and throws `TypeError: can't iterate from NilClass` when attempting to iterate. I just ran into this on a project with a date range input testing it against bogus user entries like nothing or random strings, etc.

Comment: Other objects could have method #each, the better answer (below) would be to see if it is Enumerable.

Comment: @saneshark: type testing in a duck-typed language? I don't think so, not idiomatic.

Answer (score 49):

You already got some answers, but here are two more ways, [Object#is_a?/Object#kind_of?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and [Module#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D):

```
  [].is_a? Enumerable #=> true
  "".is_a? Enumerable #=> false

  Enumerable === [] #=> true
  Enumerable === "" #=> false
```

Comment: This is not working as `Hash` is a `Enumerable` too but it shouldn't not be recognized as a collection in most use cases

Comment: 1. OP didn't ask about "collections", but about "[h]ow to check if an object is iterable in Ruby?" (literally the title of the question). Being an `Enumberable` is pretty much the definition of that in Ruby.

2. Java refers to its `HashMap` as a collection, .Net's `Dictionary` is defined in `System.Collections.Generic`, so the assertion that they are not recognized as "collections" seems arbitrary.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type), point "2.3. Associative Arrays", which is exactly what a Ruby `Hash` is.

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on your larger goals and what you need to do with the result.

1. If you just want to use duck typing to see if the object responds to **#each**, then you can just ask the object if it has such a method.

   ```
   my_object.respond_to? :each
   ```
2. If you want to find out if the object mixes in the Enumerable class, you can check the class for inclusion.

   ```
   my_object.class.include? Enumerable
   ```
3. If you want a list of all the ancestors and mixins, you want the [#ancestors](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) method. For example, to see whether **my_object** inherits from the Enumerable class, you could invoke:

   ```
   my_object = []
   my_object.class.ancestors
   => [Array, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]

   my_object.class.ancestors.include? Enumerable
   => true
   ```

Comment: Why use `my_object.class.include? Enumerable` instead of `my_object.is_a? Enumerable`?

Comment: @dbenhur Semantic clarity. The results are generally the same.

Comment: Instead of looking at ancestors you can also check like this: `my_object.class < Enumerator`

Comment: This is not working as Hash is a Enumerable too but it shouldn't not be recognized as a collection in most use cases

Answer (score 2):

Because `Range` responds to `each` even when it isn't iterable you need to specifically check that the Range's elements respond to `succ`

```
def iterable?(object)
  return object.begin.respond_to? :succ if object.kind_of? Range
  object.respond_to? :each
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In general case you can check if `each` method is defined, or if `Enumerable` module is included in object's class:

```
my_object.class.include? Enumerable
```

Answer (score 0):

`Minitest`-style test case for `ActiveRecord` composition object:

```ruby
def test_iterates_over_invoice_items
  invoice = Invoice.new(items: [InvoiceItem.new(description: 'test')])

  iteration_count = 0
  invoice.each do |invoice_item|
    assert_equal 'test', invoice_item.description
    iteration_count += 1
  end

  assert_equal 1, iteration_count
end
```